# React router dynamic navigation panel

Tags: reactjs, nested, navigation, react-router

Having the following image, and its respective html:

[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEkhj.png)

```
<nav className="navigation">
        <div className="navigation-first">
            <div className="navigation-container">
                <Link to="/" activeClassName="active">Dashboard</Link>
                <Link to="/work" activeClassName="active">Work</Link>
                <Link to="/profile" activeClassName="active">My profile</Link>
                <Link to="/account" activeClassName="active">Account</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="navigation-second">
            <div className="navigation-container">
                <Link to="/work/jobs" activeClassName="active">Job search</Link>
                <Link to="/work/pools" activeClassName="active">Talent pools</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I want the second part to be dynamic. Let's say for every upper menu I want to have various sub-menus. Look at the router I have so far:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={MainLayout}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="work">
            <Route path="jobs">
                <Route component={SearchLayoutContainer}>
                    <IndexRoute component={JobContainer} />
                </Route>
            </Route>
            <Route path="pools">
                <Route component={SearchLayoutContainer}>
                    <IndexRoute component={PoolContainer} />
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

By the way, the navigation is coming from a component nested in views, is it that okay? For now I have this structure:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtqEL.png)

Whatever information will be welcome. Thanks a lot in advance.

PD: I have already gone through the react-router docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use route params instead of actual routes.

```
<Route path="work/:section">
```

So the `section` could be jobs or pools. You can get this variable in `WorkComponent` and render different results based on its value.

Comment: Hey Dmitriy, thanks for your answer.

What I want to achieve is, when clicking on profile or account for example, to have the second part of the navigation dynamic, with different elements.

This is probably a silly question, but I am just learning React and I need to get this working for the single page app I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is a good practice, but I have come with the following idea:

export default function(props) {
    let subMenu;

```
// Submenu
if (props.location.indexOf("work") >= 0) {
    subMenu = (
        <div className="navigation-second">
            <div className="navigation-container">
                <Link to="/work/jobs" activeClassName="active">Job search</Link>
                <Link to="/work/pools" activeClassName="active">Talent pools</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
} else {
    subMenu = (
        <div className="navigation-second">
            <div className="navigation-container">
                <Link to="/test" activeClassName="active">Test</Link>
                <Link to="/test" activeClassName="active">Test</Link>
                <Link to="/test" activeClassName="active">Test</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

return (
    <nav className="navigation">
        <div className="navigation-first">
            <div className="navigation-container">
                <Link to="/" activeClassName="active">Dashboard</Link>
                <Link to="/work" activeClassName="active">Work</Link>
                <Link to="/profile" activeClassName="active">My profile</Link>
                <Link to="/account" activeClassName="active">Account</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/* Submenu */}
        {subMenu}
    </nav>
);
```

Where props.location comes from: `props.location.pathname`